# Существительное при дробном числительном

Tags: грамматика, управление, числительные, существительные

*Районный суд приговорил его к 4,5 года лишения свободы.*
Верно ли здесь употребление существительного «года»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Правильными являются конструкции ***35,5 процента*** (не **...процентов**), ***12,6 километра*** (не **...километров**), ***0,68 квадратного (кв.) метра*** (не **…метров**),  т. е. при смешанном числе существительным управляет дробь, а не целое число; так же: ***45,0 (сорок пять и ноль десятых) секунды, 6 7/8 (шесть и семь восьмых) метра*** и т. п.

*Районный суд приговорил его к 4,5* [четырём целым пяти десятым] ***года** лишения свободы.*
При склонении дробных числительных существительное сохраняет грамматическую форму родительного падежа ([М. Карнаухова. Русский язык...](https://books.google.ee/books?id=7kw3DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC&source=bl&ots=00x4nc_8qR&sig=ACfU3U3iRPQfEENJbp4UHFneERIduQLx4Q&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAi4KhmYr5AhWhs4sKHcPdBccQ6AF6BAgbEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC&f=false)).

Если дробное число оканчивается на пять десятых (3,5; 4,5; 10,5), то почти всегда его склоняют в виде числа с половиной (три с половиной, четыре с половиной, десять с половиной), оформляют прописью.

*Районный суд приговорил его к четырём с половиной **годам** лишения свободы.*

Затем они приняли как неопровержимое мнение, что давление в центре Земли на глубине 6370 километров равно **трем с половиной миллионам** атмосфер. [Во всем мире // «Знание ― сила», 1988]

Рита нисколько не удивилась, но в загсе сидели бюрократы и отказались регистрировать, потому что до восемнадцати ей не хватало **пяти с половиной** месяцев. [Борис Васильев. А зори здесь тихие (1969)]

[Форма существительного при смешанном числе](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5/)

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того, как читать дробь.

**"К четырём с половиной годам"**,
но
**"К четырём целым пяти десятым го́да"** ([в таких случаях согласование идёт по знаменателю](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=291585)).

Верны оба варианта.

Comment: Читаем такое по второй схеме...  вот мне хотелось написать «годам» приговорен... Но ведь пяти десятым чего? года правильно

Comment: Не стоит смешивать системы. Трудно представить запись *четыре целых семь десятых года*.